# Identify inactivity of Swing application

Tags: java, swing, session-timeout

I would like to implement session timeout kind of thing for a `JFrame`. My Swing application has login authentication but no invalidation after certain period of inactivity. I have one way (idea) of doing it, like checking timestamps of last two successive events (key or mouse). I think there has to be an elegant way of achieving this.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I have one way (idea) of doing it, like checking timestamps of last two successive events (key or mouse)

Thats reasonable. [Application Inactivity](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/application-inactivity/) shows an easy way to globally listen for these events.

Answer (score 2):

[Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Start timer. Cancel it any time an action is performered. If it goes off, you know they've been inactive.